# Web2Py Resizing a textbox

Tags: web2py

I have been trying to resize a text box in a custom form with Web2py.

```
contact=SQLFORM.factory(
        Field('your_email',requires=IS_EMAIL()),
        Field('question', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()))
   contact.custom.submit['_value'] = 'Send'
   contact.element('input[name=question]')['_style']='width:150px'
```

The above works, but i need the Field 'question' to be a multi line input. When i change its type to 'text' with:

```
Field('question','text' requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()))
```

I can no longer resize the text box with the above code.

how would i resize a textbox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's now a textarea, not an input, so try:

```
contact.element('textarea[name=question]')['_style'] = 'width:150px;height:50px;'
```

Comment: Is there a way to allow the user to resize the control by dragging it?